# Unable to define proper Object in VBA for a Copy Paste Template Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that copies a range of cells that has a template with text set up and pastes that template into another range of cells on a different sheet in one workbook.

Here's what I have:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397, [D429]")

Dim NewTemplate As Variant
NewTemplate = Sheets("clin obs 2").Range("A430, [D462]")

Sub ClinOb_Copy_Paste()

ClinObTemplate.Select
Selection.Copy
NewTemplate.Select
Selection.Paste


End Sub
```

Should I define these variables As String? I keep receiving Runtime Error 424: Object Required, but I can't seem to define my object.

I'm brand new to VBA and programming, so I really appreciate the help!

Thank you!

Comment: glad to hear it worked, please mark my answer or @Telestia's answer as correct for moderation purposes and we'll consider this one a success. Here's a screen-shot that breaks it down: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ClinOb_Copy_Paste2()

Dim ClinObRange As Range, NewObRange As Range
Dim ClinObsSheet1 As Worksheet, ClinObsSheet2 As Worksheet

'set references up-front
Set ClinObsSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("clin obs")
Set ClinObsSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("clin obs 2")
With ClinObsSheet1
    Set ClinObRange = .Range("A397:D429")
End With
With ClinObsSheet2
    Set NewObRange = .Range("A430:D462")
End With

'do work
ClinObRange.Copy NewObRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Dan Wagner, this is working and I'm able to manipulate it. Very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You should define them as Excel's built in Range type. You should also be defining them inside the subroutine, unless you need them across multiple subs or functions. You should also read this: [Avoiding using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select).

After cleaning up the code a bit, this is what I came up with.

```
Sub ClinOb_Copy_Paste()
 Dim ClinObTemplate As Range
 ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397, [D429]")

 Dim NewTemplate As Range
 Set NewTemplate = Sheets("clin obs 2").Range("A430, [D462]")
 ClinObTemplate.Copy NewTemplate
End Sub
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @telestia, for your response. I had to play around with this a bit but defining the variables As Range has resolved the object undefined issue.

Comment: Good recommendation on avoiding select

Comment: KyleC.Dwyer, I'm glad I could help! @Dan Wagner, Thanks! That answer has saved me so much time and frustration, I like to share it at every opportunity!

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons your code fails.

If you want to work with objects, you assign them to variables using `Set`. Even if you declare your variable as `Variant` type, it will still work provided you use `Set`. However, it is always advisable to explicitly declare the type of variable you want to work with. Why?

- It helps in stability, readability and allows you to detect type mismatches.
- It is faster.

So this would have worked:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
Set ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397,D429")
```

But of course, what Dan posted is advisable.
Now, as you can see there's a difference in how I've constructed the `Range Object` syntax.
Let's take a look at your code:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397, [D429]")
```

Above would've resulted to `Error 1004`.
If you've noticed, I remove the `[]` brackets on the `D429` address.
 Why?
Because `[]` have special meaning in `VBA`. 
It is a shortcut for `Evaluate`.
`[D429]` is actually evaluating the address `D429` and actually returns a `Range Object`.
So to make your code work with brackets `[]`, it should be like this:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
Set ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397," & [D429].Address)
```

Now your `ClinOnTemplate` variable contains the `Range Object` A397 and D429.
If however you want to select the entire range in between those boundaries like A397:D429, write your code like this:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
Set ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397", [D429])
```

Or this:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
Set ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range("A397:" & [D429].Address)
```

Or even this:

```
Dim ClinObTemplate As Variant
Set ClinObTemplate = Sheets("clin obs").Range([A397], [D429])
```

All codes assigns the `Range Object A397:D429` to `ClinObTemplate` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the breakdown, I would VU if I could. Very helpful.

Comment: @KyleC.Dwyer No problem. Btw, what do you mean by `VU`? :)

Comment: @L42 by VU I meant Vote Up.

Comment: @L42 Requires 14rep, I'm on my way! haha